# Does ActiveMQ have a reactive client library or a way to get messages with spring WebClient?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am working on an NIO SMTP client with Spring Webflux and Reactor Netty. I have a requirement to integrate messaging into the application, and I was wondering if there is a non blocking way to interact with ActiveMQ, the only documentation I found that mentions NIO in ActiveMQ only talks about how the ActiveMQ server uses NIO model, but nothing about consuming the service with a non blocking client.

Comment: ActiveMQ has a REST API that can be used to both produce and consume messages.  (see http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html)  Therefore, you could use Spring Webflux to connect with the ActiveMQ REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, ActiveMQ, like any other JMS provider has a blocking API ([MessageConsumer.receive()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive-long-)) as well as a method to setup a [MessageListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageListener.html) that is called automatically once a message arrives. Since you are using Spring, take a look at [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/) example.

In addition, you can enable server-side NIO with 'nio' instead of the tcp prefix: nio://hostname:port?key=value, see also https://activemq.apache.org/nio-transport-reference, but it sounds like NIO is implemented only the server end of a client-server communication only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, perhaps I should have been clearer in my question. I understand that there is a way to set up a listener for the messages; however, as far as I understand, the listener itself still uses a blocking call to listen to the incoming messages. I am talking specifically about a NIO socket implementation, similar to that of the Spring Webflux Webclient, or a Reactor-Netty TCP client.